# Reactive Variables for Server Side RESTful Route with iron:router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

For the first time in my Meteor career, I'm deploying a production application that handles RESTful routes in response to webhooks.

I've noticed that in production, variables will don't reset, they just keep adding new data ontop of themselves.

I would like to leverage reactive variables on the server to accomplish this goal.

How can I use iron:router to it's full potential with reactivity? I need to process requests dynamically as they come in, assign certain fields to variables, then make a POST request with new values.

My code looks like this...

```
Router.route('/webhooks/shopify', { where: 'server' })
  .post(function() {
    // CANT USE var since it's not reactive

    // var order = this.request.body;


    // call this method with the proper ID and FIELDS variable

    // Meteor.call('updateOrder', id, fields, function(error, result) {
    //   if (!error) {
    //     console.log('successfully updated!', result);
    //   }
    // });
  });
```